# How to shorten `if-statement`

Tags: php, loops, optimization

I have an `if` statement in my foreach loop. The condition is about 125 characters long. Are there other ways to shorten this?

```
if ($col == 'foo' || $col == 'bar' || $col == 'baz' || $col == 'fubar' || $col == 'spam' || $col == 'eggs') {
    continue;
}
```

NOTE: sorry for the confusion on the condition values guys, `'a'`, `'b'`, ... were meant to be various strings.

Comment: the first question is always: "what are you actually trying to do". Are you trying to match words in a list? Are you trying to match string patterns? are you trying to match something in PHP that you're retrieving from a database and could make the database do instead? You have 3 answers already and none of them tried to find out what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm trying to match words in a list (col).. the condition is meant to be exceptions on what I want to display on the page.

Comment: your example is also extremely contrived: it seems extremely unlikely that these are the actual words you want to stop filtering on, so: add more details. Instead of using toy words, describe what you're *actually* doing, and you might get a much more accurate, much more useful answer (because it feels like you asked an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)-style question)

Comment: I think I stated my problem correctly. `Are there other ways to shorten this?`. I did not post exact values since I want the confidentiality of my project to be private. I was not seeking for answers with the exact parameter values just like on my question. I was looking for answers that will shorten/simplify my code.

Comment: I know, but your use of `$col` suggests this is a database pull, for instance, in which case: why make PHP do what your database can already filter out? You don't have to use your exact data, but the way you present what you need done can lead to incredibly efficient solutions, which you won't get if you use "foo" and "bar".

Comment: `foreach ($checklist as $col => $val)` ~ `$checklist` is an array derived from a database pull concerning a Model with a many-to-many relationship models. Since I don't want to mess with the model structure, I just posted a concise-what-my-problem's-scope-question instead. I know, I have a tangled model structure, but this is a collaborative work.. so, what can I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Store all elements in single dimension array first, in your case this will be look like:

```
$array = array('a','b','c','d','e','f');
```

Then use php in built function in_array() to check whether $col exists in array, in your this looks like:

```
in_array($col, $array);
```

Entire code:

```
$array = array('a','b','c','d','e','f');
if(in_array($col, $array)) {
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use an array:

```
if(in_array($col, ['a','b','c','d','e','f'])) {
    continue;
}
```

But be aware than this is not really an optimisation, more of a readability enhancement. There's nothing wrong with your previous statement.

Answer (score 2):

i would use the fact that there are usually ascii so you could do something like

```
 if ($col >= 'a' && $col <='f') {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: um, sorry, I meant the strings to be variables. what if I have english words as the column values?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if (in_array($col, array('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'fubar', 'spam', 'eggs'))
{
    continue;
}
```

If you're using PHP 5.4+, you can make it look a bit more elegant:

```
if (in_array($col, ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'fubar', 'spam', 'eggs'])
{
    continue;
}
```

If you need strict comparison, as in `'x' === $x`, add `, true` to the `in_array()` call.